total value coming incorrect in a matrix
AVG $ UNIT CFY =
DIVIDE(
[CY Sales],
[Qty Sold CFY],
0
) . for me also the total in the matrix giving totals divided .instead adding all the numbers. please help me on this
i need the total to be corrected, individual values are right but total are wrong

you can try to use
=SUMX(values([rowcolumn]), AVG $ UNIT CFY )


Please provide an explanation as of why this would resolve the problem
